# Buscar strings diferentes entre dos textos (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string, loops

Necesito encontrar palabras diferentes y pequeñas frases de longitud de hasta 5 palabras (o podría ser personalizable) de un texto dentro de otro. Las diferencias quiero guardarlas en un array, de tal forma que solo se guarden las palabras o frases sin repetir (se comprueba antes si ya existe).
De momento he conseguido que me busque las palabras diferentes, pero no sé cómo hacer que ahora siga buscando frases de 2 palabras (consecutivas), en la siguiente iteración de 3 palabras, 4... y así sucesivamente

```
    var texto = "Aquí va el el primer texto a analizar e incluso con palabras repetidas repetidas";
    var texto2 = "Aquí va el segundo texto a analizar analizar e incluso con algunas palabras repetidas";

    var palabras = texto.split(" ");
    var palabras2 = texto2.split(" ");

    var diferentes = [];

    var max_palabras = 3;
    var max_busquedas = 50; //hasta que diferentes.length>=50
    var cont_palabras = 0;
    var frase = "";
    var newStr = "";
    var addWord = false;

    do {


        for (var i=0; i<palabras.length; i++) {

            console.log("añade palabra = "+addWord);

            if (texto2.includes(palabras[i]) == false) {

                if (diferentes.includes(palabras[i]) == false) { //si no existe en el array de diferencias
                    diferentes.push(palabras[i]);
                }
            }

            if (cont_palabras < 1) {
                frase = palabras[i];
                console.log("FRASE = "+frase);
            } 

            if (cont_palabras >= 1 && addWord == true) {

                frase = frase + " " + palabras[i+cont_palabras];
                addWord = false;    
                console.log("FRASE = "+frase);

                console.log("Nueva frase construida (cont = "+ (cont_palabras+1) +") = "+ frase);
            }


        }

        cont_palabras++;
        addWord = true;

    } while (cont_palabras <= max_palabras);


    for (var i=0; i<palabras2.length; i++) {

      if (texto.includes(palabras2[i]) == false) {

         if (diferentes.includes(palabras2[i]) == false) { //si no existe en el array de diferencias
            diferentes.push(palabras2[i]);
         }
      }
    }

    for (var j=0; j<diferentes.length; j++) {
       console.log("Elemento "+ j + " diferente en ambos textos = "+diferentes[j])
    }
```

**Cómo puedo hacer que cada vez me vaya cogiendo una palabra más del texto1 y analizando si existe en el texto2, buscando siempre todas las frases posibles (pero las palabras deben ser consecutivas)**

PD. He vuelto a actualizar el código con algo de progreso, pero ahora no sé cómo hacer que recurra el texto de 2 en 2 palabras, de 3 en 3...etc

Comment: ¿Podrías poner la salida que esperas teniendo los dos textos que expones?

Comment: La salida será un array con una larga lista, ya que sacará strings de 1palabra, 2 palabras, 3palabras... Por ejemplo, la salida será: ["primer","segundo","algunas","el primer", "el segundo", "primer texto a", "segundo texto a" ...] . No se si me he explicado, en definitiva todas las frases posibles que sean diferentes, siempre y cuando las palabras vayan seguidas. Gracias Pablo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ver si esto se aproxima a lo que buscas.

Lo que hace la función `checkDifferences` es buscar las cadenas coincidentes entre los dos textos y obtener el resto como diferencias.

Si quieres luego podrías descomponer las diferencias más largas en elementos más pequeños.

La función `checkDifferencesByLength` busca en el primer texto grupos de palabras de una longitud determinada que no existen en el segundo.

```js
function checkDifferences(text1, text2){
  if (text1.length && text2.length){
    var words1 = text1.split(' ');
    var words2 = text2.split(' ');
    // Busca la mayor coincidencia
    for(var i=(words1.length > words2.length ? words2.length : words1.length); i > 0; i--){
      for(var j=0; j<=words1.length - i; j++){
        var pattern = words1.slice(j, j+i).join(' ');
        var coincidence = text2.indexOf(pattern);
        if (coincidence >= 0){
          // Coincidencia encontrada
          // Objeto diferencias de los textos anteriores a la coincidencia
          var differencesBefore = checkDifferences(words1.slice(0, j).join(' '),
                                      text2.substring(0, coincidence).trim());
          // Objeto diferencias de los textos posteriores a la coincidencia
          var differencesAfter = checkDifferences(words1.slice(j+i).join(' '),
                                      text2.substring(coincidence + pattern.length).trim());
          // Devuelve diferencias anteriores, posteriores y coincidencia actual
          return{
            differences1: differencesBefore.differences1.concat(differencesAfter.differences1),
            differences2: differencesBefore.differences2.concat(differencesAfter.differences2),
            coincidences: differencesBefore.coincidences.concat([pattern], differencesAfter.coincidences)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // No se ha encontrado coincidencias
  return {
    differences1: text1.length ? [text1] : [],
    differences2: text2.length ? [text2] : [],
    coincidences: []
  };
}

function checkDifferencesByLength(text1, text2, length){
  var words1 = text1.split(' ');
  if (words1.length < length) return null;
  
  var differences = [];
  for (var i=0; i+length<=words1.length; i++){
    var pattern = words1.slice(i, i+length).join(' ');
    if (text2.indexOf(pattern)<0) differences.push(pattern);
  }
  return differences;
}

var texto = "Aquí va el el primer texto a analizar e incluso con palabras repetidas repetidas";
var texto2 = "Aquí va el segundo texto a analizar analizar e incluso con algunas palabras repetidas";

var result = checkDifferences(texto, texto2);

console.log('Primer texto: ' + texto);
console.log('Segundo texto: ' + texto2);

console.log('Coincidencias:\n' + result.coincidences.join('\n'));
console.log('Elementos diferentes en primer texto:\n' + result.differences1.join('\n'));
console.log('Elementos diferentes en segundo texto:\n' + result.differences2.join('\n'));

var resultByLength = checkDifferencesByLength(texto, texto2, 4);
console.log('Grupos de 4 palabras del primer texto que no existen en el segundo:\n'
  + resultByLength.join('\n'));
resultByLength = checkDifferencesByLength(texto2, texto, 4);
console.log('Grupos de 4 palabras del segundo texto que no existen en el primero:\n'
  + resultByLength.join('\n'));
```

Comment: Hola Asier, no es exactamente lo que busco, aunque la verdad que se asemeja bastante a la solución. Me gustaría encontrar tanto palabras sueltas como frases distintas de hasta X palabras. Por ejemplo, si especifico en la función por parámetro: 4 palabras, me podría sacar la frase "Aquí va el el", que en el primer texto está, pero en el segundo no. De todas formas muchas gracias, y miraré tu posible solución

Comment: Bueno eso sería incluso más sencillo. He modificado el ejemplo para añadir una función `checkDifferencesByLength` que busca textos con una longitud de palabras determinada que no existan en un segundo texto. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Perfecto! No tengo más que decir, ahora sí que es lo que estaba buscando. Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda Asier!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function shorter(max,s1,s2){
var arr1 = s1.split(" "), arr2 = s2.split(" "), i = 0, l1 = arr1.length, unicas = [];
  for(;i<l1;i++){
    if((arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]) === -1) && arr1[i].length <= max) unicas.push(arr1[i]);
  }
  return unicas;
}


var texto = 
"Aquí va el el primer texto a analizar e incluso con palabras repetidas repetidas";
var texto2 = 
"Aquí va el segundo texto a analizar analizar e incluso con algunas palabras repetidas";
console.log(shorter(6,texto,texto2));
```